# unity rigging png and psd files with bones refusing to work

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm trying to add bones and rig this rectangle, however the "create bone" option won't work and I can't create a single bone. This won't work for either png or psd files.

[image: screenshot of what I see]

I'm fairly new to adding bones so please try to be paitient with me

, thanks -Jake

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the error, I was using `psd and png` instead of `psb` files